# LPWSTR comparison

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How do I properly deal with the `if` statement in this example:

```
int n_args = 0;
int i;
LPWSTR *args = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &n_args);
if (args)
{
    if (n_args >= 2)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < n_args; i++)
        {
            std::cout << args[i] << "\n";
            if (args[i] == L"/D") // <-- here
            {
                std::cout << "Condition met\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first `std::cout` shows that the command line parameter has been passed, but the following `if` statement fails.

Comment: Also, `std::cout` does not have an `<<` operator that accepts a `wchar_t*` as input, so this code will invoke the `<<` operator that takes a `void*` as input, and thus print out the memory address the pointer is holding, not the string content that it is pointing at.  Use `std::wcout` instead to print wide strings, or else convert `args[i]` to Ansi before printing it with `std::cout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (wcscmp(L"/D", args[i]) == 0)
{
```

You are trying to compare two pointer values. You need to use `strcmp` or it's wide character string version `wcscmp`. This function returns 0 when the strings contain the same content.

Comment: The Win32 API has its own `lstrcmpW()` and `CompareStringW()`/`CompareStringEx()` functions (amongst others), whereas `wcscmp()` is from the C runtime library.  Just pointing out there are multiple ways to compare string values using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

args[i] is a string. you need use wcscmp or strcmp to compare two strings.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx